# robocopy files from multiple source folder to a single destination using powershell

Tags: powershell

I've multiple source folder starting with z00* and i need to copy these folders to a single destination

I am able to copy files from particular source to particular destination

```
#region header
#   File:       Robocopy.ps1
#   Descripion: This Script triggers Robocopy Job and sents an email notification with the job status at the end of the script. 
#   Author:     Anubhav Das
#   Date:       01.07.2019
#endregion header

$date = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm")
$log = "M:\Projects\USI\Robocopy\Robocopy_logs\Robocopy_log_$date.txt"
$robocopydump = "M:\Projects\USI\Robocopy\Robocopy_logs\eagle_$date.txt"
$src = "M:\Projects\USI\z003nr2u"
$dst = "T:\Anubhav\input-files"

#####################################

#email settings#

$smtp = 'mail.xxx.xx'
$frm = "anubhav.das@xxx.com"
$sbjerror = "Robocopy Job failed"
$sbjsuccess = "Robocopy Job Complete"
$admin = @("anubhav.das@xxx.com")
$bdy = "M:\Projects\USI\Robocopy\mail.txt"

Write-Logs -logFile $log -content "############### Starting Script ################"

### Roboopy Job##
Write-Logs -logFile $log -content "Robocopy job starting"
Robocopy.exe $src $dst /MIR /NP /MT >> $robocopydump
Write-Logs -logFile $log -content "Robocopy job ended"
Write-Logs -logFile $log -content 
#####################################   

$sizedst = get-datasize -targetDir $dst
Write-Logs -logFile $log -content "Total size of destination after sync = $sizedst GB"

write-logs -logFile $log -content "####### END OF SCRIPT #######"

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -Port 25 -From $frm -To $admin - 
Subject $sbjsuccess -Body ((Get-Content $bdy | Out-String)+(Get-Content 
$robocopydump -Tail 10 | Out-String)) -Attachments $robocopydump

Get-ChildItem T:\Anubhav\input-files -recurse -include *.txt | remove-item
$folders = Get-ChildItem T:\Anubhav\input-files
foreach ($folder in $folders.name){
Copy-Item -Path "M:\Projects\USI\Robocopy\Robocopy_logs\eagle_$date.txt" 
-Destination "T:\Anubhav\input-files\$folder" -Recurse
}
```

While i try with dynamic source i.e. $src = "M:\Projects\USI\z00*" i get an error invalid source parameter.

Since i'm having multiple folders starting from z00* i'm unable to make source path.

Comment: Questions about how to parametrize Robocopy would be on-topic at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: couldn't find relative topic on SuperUser.